# Calculate probabilities from xgb dump for multi:softprob objective - formula?

Tags: boosting

On dumping the xgboost (with objective of multi:softprob) for binary classification, I see booster dumps as: class0_booster0, class1_booster0, class0_booster1, class1_booster1, etc. I have noted down all the leaf values for class 0. How do I, then, calculate the probability for class 0? (I've tried 1/1+exp(-S), where S is the sum of all leaves, but had no luck.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, could figure out! So, needed to do the following steps (per feature vector):

- Get all the leaf values for all the boosters (both classes). Note that if the feature-attribute value is a zero, you'd have to take the child under missing=<> (by default xgb considers zeros as 'missing')
- Sum up all the leaf values for each class separately: call them sum1, sum2 resp.
- Add the bias_score to each sum (by default, it is 0.5): sum1 += 0.5, sum2 += 0.5.
- Then apply the multi-class Softmax function to get the final probabilities for the two classes! i.e.
  exp(sum1)/(exp(sum1)+exp(sum2)), likewise,
  exp(sum2)/(exp(sum1)+exp(sum2)) respectively.

Comment: Just per my experience, and for changes that may have occurred to XGBoost since this question was asked.  zero valued a missing depends on both the booster and how the data was provided to xgboost.  If it was provided as dense data, then 0's aren't missing, it it is sparse then they are missing.  Likewise for regression based problems, the linear booster will treat 0's as missing also (albeit not in the scope of this question).